# Javascript RSA implementation doesn't generate correctly

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, primes, number-theory

The problem is at generating either e or d. But what? The math seems good to me.

e > 1 and coprime to ϕ

d satisfies de≡1(modϕ(n))

Please help

```js
var m = 4, //Message
    p = 13
    q = 7

    n = p * q
    T = (q - 1) * (p - 1)
    d = new Number;


//Calculate e:
for (let i = 2; i < T; i++) {

    if( (gcd(i,T) == 1) ) { var e = i; break; }
}

//Calculate d:
while ( e * d % T != 1 ) d++;

function gcd(k, n) {
    return k ? gcd(n % k, k) : n;
}


var e_m = m ** e % n,      // To encrypt
    d_m = e_m ** d % n    // To decrypt

console.log(`m: ${m}\np: ${p}\nq: ${q}\nn: ${n}\nT: ${T}\n\ne: ${e}\nd: ${d}\n\nencrypted: ${e_m}\ndecrypted: ${d_m}`);

//Results:
// encrypted: 23
// decrypted: 28 (not 4)
```

Comment: Javascript numbers have limited precision (53 bits for exact integer values), but your decryption line `d_m = e_m ** d % n` first computes `e_m ** d` and then takes that result mod `n`. However `23 ** 29` is a 132-bit integer, way too large to store the exact result.

Comment: Oh okay thank you. I guess I gotta use a bignum library.

Comment: No, not necessarily, at least for numbers of the size in your example. You need to use [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) function that reduces intermediate results as it goes.

Comment: Ah, so ((e_m % n) ** (d % n)) % n, it worked. Thank you so much!